# Glyphicon icon not appear on first page and after refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap.min.css on bootstrap v3.3.5. I download the bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com and used it locally. I notice there is a problem with glyphicons when run on IE 9 and above. The glyphicon icon will disappear on first page after login and disappear again when we refresh (F5) on the page.

```
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/assets/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I switch to using bootstrap.min.css from a CDN I don't have the error.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Please help. I don't know what is different between the local and online bootstrap.min.css

Thank you.

Comment: try to check on refresh the value of request.getContextPath()

Comment: I check the value of request.getContextPath() before and after refresh, its the same.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will help you...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Glyphicon Examples</h2>
  <p>Envelope icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></p>    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: i want to used the local bootstrap.min.css. i already customize some of the code in it.

Comment: It will become like this <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> ?

Comment: if you are using Visual Studio just drag the files in header section and this will work for u

Comment: I'm using eclipse Helios. I already setting the file path correctly, but it still happen.