# Bootstrap Glyphicons not visibile after refreshing IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, https, glyphicons

If I start the Project with Visual Studio(2013) and choose HTTPS the first time the application starts I see the glyphicons but not if I refresh the page.
If I do the same with HTTP then I dont have this Problem.
In my web.Config I don't use Cache and I also checked the Font Folder everything seems OK. 
I saw many similar question on stackoverflow like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748140/font-face-eot-not-loading-over-https#answer-29383741)
or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429114/glyphicon-icon-not-appear-on-first-page-and-after-refresh-page)  but nothing helped.

Comment: What version of IE? Check network tab in F12 dev tools in browser to see if any errors?

Comment: IE 11. No errors in network tab